# Retrieving list of files in certain folder in AWS S3(v 2.4.4) and deleting them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm making Angular/Rails app and upgraded Rails from 4.2.x to 5.0.0 and AWS-SDK from 1.6.x to 2.4.4.

1) I used to able to retrieve files from certain path in my AWS S3 bucket using the following syntax:

```
@files = @bucket.objects.with_prefix("path/to/folder")
```

After upgrading the AWS to the 2.4.4 version it is saying

```
(undefined method `with_prefix' for #<Aws::Resources::Collection:______>
```

I read new doc and found `bucket.objects(prefix: '/tmp-files/')` but this did not work for my appand said `ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0))`.

2) Let's say I need to delete a file name `sample.pdf` in a path `sample/pdf/`. I was doing `@bucket.objects['sample/pdf/sample.pdf']` and not working. Is there something wrong with this syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have syntax error, options need to be a Hash. Your command should be:

```
bucket.objects({prefix: '/tmp-files/'})
```

For more options, refer docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Bucket.html#objects-instance_method

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@bucket.objects(prefix: '/tmp-files-path/').delete
```

[Here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby#resource-interfaces-aws-sdk-resources-gem) is the official doc for the same.

Comment: Do you have an idea about retrieving files?

Comment: `@bucket.objects(prefix: '/directory-path/')` to get the list of files

Comment: Are you saying I call `@bucket.objects(prefix: 'directory path')`? I wrote in my question that this does not work and returns argument error

Comment: have you tried this? `s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new

# reference an existing bucket by name
bucket = s3.bucket('bucket-name')

# enumerate every object in a bucket
bucket.objects.each do |obj|
  puts "#{obj.key} => #{obj.etag}"
end`

Comment: the one above your answer is a correct answer. Thank you for the try tho. I want to ask you one thing. Is there a way to land on exactly on object instead of bunch using prefix?